# How to validate number against 0.5 incremental using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate a javascript string against 0.5 incrementals. So for exmaple..

```
var number = 1      //true
var number = 1.2    //false
var number = 1.5    //true
var number = 2.8    //false
var number = 4      //true
var number = 0.5    //true
var number = 10.4   //false
```

I'm wondering if someone can help me get started with something like this. Would perhaps regex be involved?

```
function validateNumber(value){
    //Do validation
}
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: It appears JS uses bstr, so a quick modulus check is all you need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use modulus operator `%` which the returns remainder.

```
function validateNumber(value){
   return value % 0.5 == 0; 
}
```

Comment: Is `%` operator in JS applicable to `float` operands?

Comment: @hindmost In JS there is no difference between integers and floats. There are only numbers.

Comment: Pretty sure that while this works for a `.5` decimal, it will not work for others because of floating point representation issues.

Comment: Actually I meant wouldn't `0.5` be casted to integer before `%` application?

Comment: @Oriol: He was asking about the operator. Some operators do coerce floats to integers.

Comment: @squint Could you name some? I'd like to know which ones.

Comment: @0x47686F7374: All bitwise operators in JavaScript do.

Comment: while this is the obvious solution, mine is faster ^^  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26282006/2768053

Answer (score 3):

Since times 2 is one of the most efficient operations, this is probably faster than using %:

```
function validateNumber(value) {
   return 2*value==Math.round(2*value)
}
```

A faster version which doesn't need to call round.

(SO FAR THIS IS THE FASTEST SOLUTION TO THE ANSWER: http://jsperf.com/modulus-vs-times2 )

```
function validateNumber(value) {
   return 2*value==2*value>>0
}
```

Comment: "probably faster" proof?

Comment: times 2 is just a binary shift, % implies dividing... need more proof?

Comment: Make a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/)! I bet it's a micro-optimization issue but I'm curious now.

Comment: @RubenSerrate both * and % operators on integers are executed in one CPU clock, aside from the JS overhead. And actually you're calling a function in your code (Math.round()), which has a much higher overhead than Amit Joki's solution

Comment: Proof: http://jsperf.com/javascript-test-for-0-5-increments your code is 95% SLOWER (I'd say that's mostly because of Math.round() )

Comment: @RubenSerrate as stated above, "aside from the JS overhead". Anyways, your code in the benchmark is faster, ok, but by 0.77%. Talk about micro-optimizations...

Comment: While this might be faster, it's less obvious what it's doing. Unless you're doing a LOT of these (and have benchmarked your code to realize this is the part causing trouble), it's probably better to use the more descriptive, slower version.

Answer (score 0):

```
\d*\.?5?
```

Try this.This works.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qZ0uP0/3

Comment: How about trailing zeros?

Comment: Modulus is more efficient than regex, methinks, but this will work aside from trailing 0s

Comment: @DanilGaponov 0* at end will do it :)

Comment: Technically, this matches the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It's overkill, but this could be done using HTML5 validation:

```
var validateNumber = (function() {
    var inp = document.createElement('input');
    inp.type = 'number';
    inp.step = 0.5;
    return function validateNumber(value) {
        inp.value = value;
        return !inp.validity.stepMismatch;
   };
})();
```

Of course, in practice use [@AmitJoki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26281951/1529630).